# spring boot UUID converter

Tags: spring-boot, converters

> Spring boot version:2.4.0

> Converter class

```
import java.util.UUID;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component 
public class StringToUuidConverter implements Converter<String, UUID> { 
    @Override
    public UUID convert(@NonNull String uuid) {
        return  UUID.fromString(uuid);
    }
}
```

controller

```
....
@Autowired
    TestRepos testRepos;
    
    @RequestMapping("test")
    public Task t( UUID uuid) {
        
        return this.testRepos.findById(uuid).orElse(null);
    }
 ....
```

call the controller with
http://localhost:9090/test?uuid=0459828a-a630-491d-80b9-ab9a412f066e

> error log

```
"error": "Bad Request",
    "trace": "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor$1: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 2 errors\nField error in object 'UUID' on field 'mostSigBits': rejected value [null]; codes [typeMismatch.UUID.mostSigBits,typeMismatch.mostSigBits,typeMismatch.long,typeMismatch];
```

Any config missed?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```java
public Task t(@RequestParam UUID uuid) {
    // ...
}
```

- [1.3.3. Handler Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.4/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-methods)

> Any other argument:
>
> If a method argument is not matched to any of the earlier values in this table and it is a simple type (as determined by [`BeanUtils#isSimpleProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.4/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html#isSimpleProperty-java.lang.Class-), it is a resolved as a `@RequestParam`. Otherwise, it is resolved as a `@ModelAttribute`.

In addition, you don't need create `StringToUuidConverter` class yourself.
[It has been already included](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.3.4/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/convert/support/StringToUUIDConverter.java).